# Why are my imageView animation so lag in big screen android device

Tags: android, animation, imageview

i'm android beginner and trying to program an android app that can dynamic add imageViews to the basic RelativeLayout. It's perform well in my android device but perform poorly in my friend's device which has a big size of screen. I googled for very long time but can't find the solution. Below are part of my code, can anyone help me?

```
    ImageView im = new ImageView(GameActivity.this);    
    im.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param =new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(imageWidth,imageHeight); 
    wholeView.addView(im, param);

    im.setX(x);
    im.setY(y);
    im.setRotation((float) (-15 + Math.random() * 30 + 90));
    dealAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(-x,0,-y,0);
    dealAnimation.setDuration(500);
    dealAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);
    im.startAnimation(dealAnimation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the size of the bitmaps that you are addding to each ImageView? Which is the total amount of bitmaps that you are adding and in how many time do you performe this operation?

When you say "my device" and "big size of screen", what exactly you mean?

Maybe you're trying to load a very large bitmap? Another point is that you are using the class **BitmapFactory** which means that you are decoding the bitmap. A large bitmap will use a very large amount of memory when decoded.

Start with appropriately scaled bitmaps, using the various drawable folders to load images (drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, etc) with a proper initial scale combined with a good distribution of your layouts for each screen size (layout-large, layout normal, etc) to avoid re-scale the bitmaps. And instead use BitmatFactory, try with `im.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My images' size are just 20KB and i just use 4 bitmap in my program. It runs well in 4.3 inch screen and lag in 5 inch screen. I'll try your solution later! By the way, is there any chance that the problem is because of the animation?

Comment: Obviously, the animation can causes the lag, more than you can imagine. And more if the animations are too consecutive. But It has not sense that in some screens goes well and in other more big not. Which terminals have you tested?